# How to compress pictures as I paste them (Word for Windows)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this VBA for Word code that inserts a picture from the clipboard and sets its size to 1.5".

---

```
Sub ResizeSelectedPicture()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
With Selection 
    .PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault) 'Pastes in the content 
    .Start = .Start - 1 'move the start back one postion to include the image 
    If .InlineShapes.Count = 1 Then 
        'resize the image 
        With .InlineShapes(1) 
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue 
            .Width = InchesToPoints(1.5) 
        End With 
    End If 
End With 

Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Exit Sub
```

---

Then I have this code that will compress all the pictures in a single document to 220ppi.

---

```
Sub CompressPics() 
If Word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then 
    Word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Select 
    SendKeys "%a%p~", True 
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress" 
End If 
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 
End Sub
```

---

Both pieces of code work very well, but I was wondering how I modify the first piece of code to compress the pictures as I paste them in and eliminate the need for the second piece of code on new documents going forward.

I tried using "InlinesShapes.Pictureformat.Compression = true" and that didn't work.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: "Then I have this code that will compress all the pictures in a single document to 220ppi." It *might* compress *one* picture. Not sure how you get that that "works very well"  for more than one picture.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious - setting the default image resolution under File | Options | Advanced? It's a per document setting which can't be set using VBA. However, if you set the default in your template it will carry through to the document.

Comment: Yeah, I already have it set to 220ppi. But pasting in my inspection photos still produces a file that is over 100Mb per report until I do the "Compress Pictures".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the CompressPics method is ok.

I have no idea of the `SendKeys "%a%p~", True`. Is this necessary?

```vb
Sub ResizeSelectedPicture()
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With selection
        .PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault) 'Pastes in the content
        .Start = .Start - 1 'move the start back one postion to include the image
        If .InlineShapes.Count = 1 Then
            'resize the image
            With .InlineShapes(1)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Width = InchesToPoints(1.5)
            End With
            rem Call the CompressPics method
            Call CompressPics ' "Call" can be omitted. Just writing 'CompressPics' is ok.
        End If
    End With
    
    selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
errorHandler:
End Sub

Sub CompressPics()
    'If Word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
    If selection.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
        'Word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Select
        SendKeys "%a%p~", True
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
    End If
    selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End Sub
```

### eliminate the need for the second piece

> and eliminate the need for the second piece of code on new documents going forward.

If you still want to do this then

```vb
Sub ResizeSelectedPictureB()
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With selection
        .PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault) 'Pastes in the content
        .Start = .Start - 1 'move the start back one postion to include the image
        If .InlineShapes.Count = 1 Then
            'resize the image
            With .InlineShapes(1)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Width = InchesToPoints(1.5)
                .Select
            End With
            SendKeys "%a%p~", True
            Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
        End If
    End With
    
    selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
errorHandler:
End Sub
```

**or**

```vb
Sub ResizeSelectedPictureB()
    Dim ur As UndoRecord
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "ResizeSelectedPicture"
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With selection
        .PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault) 'Pastes in the content
        If .Previous.InlineShapes.Count = 1 Then
            'resize the image
            With .Previous.InlineShapes(1)
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Width = InchesToPoints(1.5)
                .Select
            End With
            SendKeys "%a%p~", True
            Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
        End If
        .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ur.EndCustomRecord
Exit Sub

errorHandler:
    ur.EndCustomRecord

End Sub
```

In fact, you have not erased it but just changed the way it is written.

If you just don't want other code to be able to call it, just add the **[Private](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/private-statement)** modifier to encapsulate it:
`Private Sub CompressPics()`

In practice, functions(method, procedure, Sub() , Function, etc.) are generally simplified and purified into a single task as much as possible. Therefore, it is recommended that you do not incorporate it into *ResizeSelectedPicture* to facilitate future expansion and maintenance.

Comment: Thanks Oscar, that seems to be working perfectly now. I've also figured out why this became an issue.
Before last December I was using Windows Photos (now Photos Legacy) to view my images and insert them into my inspection reports. Then I got frustrated with how Photos was working so I switched over to a program called ImageGlass. So, long story short, when Photos copies and pastes it pastes in a copy of the file, not the image. Which results in a much smaller file. ImageGlass and the new Photos app paste in an image which winds up blowing up the size of the Word file.

Comment: So my word files when using Photos Legacy were about 2Mb when I finished my reports, but using ImageGlass or the new Photos app the file sizes went up to over 150Mb. This solves that problem.

Comment: I do wish there was more of a programmatic way of compressing the images as opposed to just calling the dialog box and mimicking pressing the keys. Any thoughts on that front?

Comment: @ChrisSalvian Did you know this Word Option? 
 `set default target output to ...`。[Turn off picture compression - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-picture-compression-81a6b603-0266-4451-b08e-fc1bf58da658)。
answer from Bing: 
Reduce the file size of your Word documents - Microsoft Support. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-the-file-size-of-your-word-documents-6c5a1186-6353-453d-bb22-e9322c2cfbab.
<https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-save-word-document-as-pdf-without-image/0bc8e7a5-e172-453c-b723-904e03724c59>.

Comment: Yeah I already have it set to 220dpi...doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @ChrisSalvian As long as you **do not check** the `Do not compress images in file` box, you will find that the resolution of the images in the file is much worse if you copy them again after reopening the file.